# How to trim a string in artillery that contains a "\n" char?

Tags: csv, post, artillery

After successfully extracting username and password from a csv as shown in the [documentation](https://artillery.io/docs/script-reference/#payload-files), I noticed that my username was in the following format: "\ntomer@mail.com". How can I erase the "\n" char in artillery?

---

P.S.

The way to check your HTTP request is (I was unable to find documentation for this):

In cmd do the following command:

```
set DEBUG=http,http:capture,http:response
```

Afterwards, every regular artillery request will give you a http debug mode as following:

```
 http request: {
  "url": "https://host.com/api/user/login",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "user-agent": "Artillery (https://artillery.io)"
  },
  "json": {
   "email": "\ntomer@mail.com",
   "password":"9526e7bb980ba35a1788d46d4a2aaaaa3d941d2efc8a4fcb1402d1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using JS as follows (solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196637/how-can-i-run-a-node-js-script-in-artillery-i-o-without-including-it-in-load-tes:))

In the config section of the yml I set that the JS file to be called would be login.js by adding the following line:

```
processor: "./js/login.js"
```

When sending my login request I called the "setJSONBody" function as following:

```
- post:
    url: "https://dev-api.host.com/api/user/login"
    beforeRequest: "setJSONBody" 
    json:
        email: "{{ user }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
```

Here is my login.js file:

```
  //
  // my-functions.js
  //
  module.exports = {
    setJSONBody: setJSONBody
  }

  function setJSONBody(requestParams, context, ee, next) {

    context.vars.user = context.vars.user.replace('\n',''); //erases from user name any \n char

    return next(); // MUST be called for the scenario to continue
  }
```